# Two circles externally tangent at $A$ meet a common external tangent line at $P$ and $Q$. If $QR$ is a diameter, prove $P$, $A$, $R$ are collinear.

Tags: geometry, circles

> If two circles are externally tangent at $A$, and a common external tangent meets the circles at $P$ and $Q$, and $QR$ is a diameter, prove that $P$, $A$, $R$ are collinear.

[image]

I’m not reaching anywhere with this proof, so any help or advice is appreciated. We don't know that PA and AR are part of the same line as that's what we want to prove. Looking at similar triangles and Thales' theorem, but don't know exactly.

Comment: Theoretically there should be an identical point $E$ that is across the diameter from $P$...  Perhaps using the fact that $\angle QAR$ would be $\frac {\pi}2$ may help.

Comment: Can you prove that $\triangle DAP \sim \triangle BAR$?

Comment: Separately, you know that the perpendiculars to the tangent line $PQ$ must be parallel, which applies to the two diameters.

Comment: @DougM Yes, I can, though I am not sure how that helps.

Answer (score 1):

$\angle QAR=90^\circ$ (angle on a semicircle).

$\angle AQP=\angle QRA$ (because both angles are $90^\circ-\angle AQR$)

Therefore $\triangle QPA \sim \triangle AQR$ (using $\angle AQP, \angle QPA$ and $\angle QRA, \angle AQR$ respectively)

Therefore $\angle PAQ=90^\circ$.

Therefore $P,A,R$ are colinear.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit on your second line? Edit: it seems like you mean angle QRA is equal to AQP because 90 - AQR

Comment: @Student; okay?

Comment: I'm also confused about how you get △∼△, as we only have one pair of angles congruent since we don't know PAQ is 90º.

Comment: @Student; two of the angles are the same, therefore they are similar.

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to prove that $\angle PAQ=90^\circ.$ Let the common tangent through $A$ intersect $PQ$ at $C$. Then by the property of tangent, one has $$CP=CA=CQ.$$ It follows that $C$ is the circumcenter of $\triangle PAQ,$ hence the triangle is a right triangle and $\angle PAQ=90^\circ.$ QED